# Updating Dataframe with Function Output

Tags: r, dataframe, function, output, tidyverse

I have written a function to remove specific columns from a dataframe and want to apply this across multiple dataframes. How can I apply the function, but then assign the output back into those original dataframes?

Here is the function:

```
f.remove_identity <- function(x) {x %>% select(-email,
   -RecipientLastName,
   -RecipientFirstName,
   -Lottery,
   -FirstName,
   -LastName,
   )}
```

I tried this to no avail:

```
f.remove_identity <- function(x) {x <- x %>% select(-email,
   -RecipientLastName,
   -RecipientFirstName,
   -Lottery,
   -FirstName,
   -LastName,
   )}
```

Any help would be appreciated, as well as correction if I am approaching this problem inefficiently.

Comment: at the very beginning of your 2nd function, include `name <- as.character(substitute(x))` then at the very  include `assign(name, x, .GlobalEnv)`. Or yu could decide to use a named list, eg `list2env(lapply(list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3), f.remove_identity), .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Using `assign` to reassign the value back to the global environment is generally a bad idea for many reasons. I suggest it's far better (easier to read/understand, clearer intentions, easier to debug) to require `mydf <- f.remove_identity(mydf)`. BTW, it might be a bit more robust to define your function as `function(x) subset(x, select = setdiff(names(x), c("email", "RecipientLastName", ...)))`. That way if one or more of the columns are not present, it will not fail, only removing columns that are actually present.